# Photoshop file dimensions for touch screen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, dimensions

I was recently tasked with creating a full screen web page for a 48" Commercial LED touch screen that is full HD 1920 x 1080 resolution and 5000:1.

Should I make the Photoshop file dimensions 1920 x 1080?

I apologize if the answer to this question is obvious.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes** your document should be 1920 x 1080 <sub>*(I can't think of a longer answer for this cause I don't know what else is needed)*</sub>

What I wanted to dig into is that 5000:1 cause I have a hunch you don't know what that means either. That's called the **contrast ratio**.

It's a new development for LCDs - “**dynamic contrast ratio,**” which has a value significantly greater than the “static” contrast ratios encountered in traditional LCD monitors.

**DCR** can achieve a value in the *5000:1* to *10000:1* range and is desirable for home use, where displays are used for gaming and movies...sooo,  what this is actually saying is that the **white areas (the brightness when the video inputs are at their maximum value) are 5000 times the brightness of the "black" (all video inputs at their minimum)**.